# Delete value from hashtable in powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I want to delete a specific value from hashtable.

The table looks like this:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                             
column                         {test, test2}
```

How can I delete the "test2" value?

I tried the following:

$myhashtable.remove("test2")

which unfortunately does not work.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example that you provided looks like a hashtable of hashtables. So you would need to do:

```
$myhashtable['column'].Remove('test2')
```

If it is a hashtable where the value is an array, then you would need to do this:

```
$myHashTable['column'] = ($myHashTable['column'] | ?{$_ -ne 'test2'})
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i have this error : Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."

Comment: I did try it and it did work. This means that it is not a hashtable of hashtables. How do you populate $myHashTable?

Comment: With a little more testing it looks like it is probably a hashtable with an array for the value. If possible I think that your best bet would be to make sure that the value doesn't get into the array to begin with. Failing that you would need to make a new array minus the unwanted value then assing that in the hashtable.

Comment: So yeah, the addition to the answer should work. Complete information when asking questions will generally get you a more complete answer for future reference.

Comment: Errr, up there where I said assing, I meant assigning.

Comment: Please provide an example of how you populate your example @EBGreen

Comment: I never populated an example. I looked at the code that the OP had and answered for his example. Nice post necro though :)